# Limit Mac users’ ability to upgrade OS X

Tags: macos

I run a mixed environment, with both Mac and Windows users on a Windows domain / Active Directory.

I have had a few users on Mac upgrade their OS without thinking of the ramifications this may have on software they use.

Is there a way to configure Macs so that only the admin user has permissions to upgrade OS?

Comment: But… only admin users can upgrade the system. Normal users (i.e., non-admins) should not be able to.

Comment: slhck is right. You must authenticate as an admin user to upgrade the system, so either your users accounts are set up as admin accounts, or they knew the login credentials for an admin account, or they used the emergency break-in procedures that allow you to create a new admin user in case you ever "lock yourself out". Are you perhaps asking how to thwart those break-in procedures that allow you to create an admin user?

Comment: I suspect he actually means the network administrator, who manages the Active Directory domain, not admin accounts on the individual machines.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is a local administrator can upgrade the OS and the machine will usually not detach from AD. So the only obvious choices for this are

1. Pull admin rights from your users. Be prepared for name calling, yelling and management escalations. The downside for you is you'll need to give them some rights granularity.
2. Modify `/etc/sudoers` to limit their abilities. This can be more complicated than #1 because it's less documented
3. If you're hosting Software Update, block the update from becoming available. Check out [**this page**](http://www.amsys.co.uk/2012/blog/os-x-server-caching-service/#.Uma4uJGIqU6) for an idea of how to do this.
4. Use a quality OSX Management Tool (I'm a big fan of JAMF's Casper Suite) that will allow you to push machine policies that will inhibit the update.

GL